# How to prevent FutureBuilder change old widget when loading?

Tags: flutter

Background: Currently I work on a remote server image viewer,I use a  `FutureBuilder`  to show image and swith between image,it work fine,but will show blank screen in some ms between switch images.

Question: I want to remain the old image widget when  `FutureBuilder`  loading or show loading circle over old image widget instead of showing new blank loading page when loading.Or any other solution without  `Futurebuilder` (like Scrollable Widget)?

the skeleton code:

```
class Viewer extends StatefulWidget {
  Viewer(this.filename, {Key key}) : super(key: key);
  final String filename;
  @override
  _ViewerState createState() {
    return _ViewerState();
  }
}

class _ViewerState extends State<Viewer> {
  int _index = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  GestureDetector(
          child: Container(
            child: showImage(context, _index),
          ),
          onPanDown: (DragDownDetails e) {
            //it will change _index to move to next image when tap down
            _index+=1;
          }
        );
  }

  Widget showImage(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return FutureBuilder<SmbHalfResult>(
      future: () async {
        //load image from remote server or from memory cache,the SmbHalfResult contain a Uint8List image.
        return SmbHalfResult();
      }(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<SmbHalfResult> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}");
          } else {
            //show image.
            return Image.memory(snapshot.data.result.content);
          }
        } else {
          // show loading circle,it will new a blank page,but I even want to display old image other than a blank page when loading.
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code?

Comment: @PrasannaKumar thank for reply kumar, I add a skeleton code, the whole code is too complicated.

Comment: Try declaring the future as a class variable and passing it to the FutureBuilder. This will prevent fetching the images every time the build function is called. **remain the old image widget when  FutureBuilder loading**. You should just return the old image instead of `CircularProgressIndicator()`

Comment: @PrasannaKumar I try this, but it still have a blank black page flicker

Comment: Try using [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider). Try changing the class `SmbHalfResult` to a provider model and call `notifylisteners()` when the new image has been fetched.

Answer (score 1):

finally I end up with [PreloadPageView](https://pub.dev/packages/preload_page_view#-readme-tab-) with paramter `physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` and `preloadPageController.jumpToPage(index)`, it perfectly meet my need without any flicker.

```
GestureDetector(
          child: Container(
              child: PreloadPageView.builder(
            preloadPagesCount: 5,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                FutureImage(index, widget.filename),
            controller: preloadPageController,
            physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          )),
          onPanDown: (DragDownDetails e) {
            Offset globalPosition = e.globalPosition;
            RenderBox findRenderObject = context.findRenderObject();
            Size size = findRenderObject.size;
            Area area = getArea(globalPosition, size);
            if (area == Area.lef) {
              index--;
              preloadPageController.jumpToPage(index);
            } else if (area == Area.right) {
              index++;
              preloadPageController.jumpToPage(index);
            }
          },
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

[Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) will be good solution for this.

In your widget tree, the widget above the **Viewer** widget must look like this

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<SmbHalfResult>(
  create: (context) {
    var smbHalfResult = SmbHalfResult(); 
    smbHalfResult.fetchImage(0);
    return smbHalfResult; 
  },  
  child: Viewer(); 
)
```

The **SmbHalfResult** class should look something similar to this

```
class SmbHalfResult extends ChangeNotifier{
  Uint8List image; 
  void fetchImage(int index) async {
    this.image = await downloadImage(index); 
    notifyListeners(); 
  }
}
```

And finally your actual UI must be like this

```
class _ViewerState extends State<Viewer> {
  int _index = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Container(
        child: Consumer<SmbHalfResult>(
          builder: (context, model) {
            if(model.image != null) return Image.memory(model.image);
            return CircularProgressIndicator(); 
          }
        ),
      ),
      onPanDown: (DragDownDetails e) {
        Provider.of<SmbHalfResult>(context, listen: false).fetchImage(); 
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I try your method, it have minimize the blank page time, but still have a little,  And I find the similar  native android app, it can swith image  without any blank page time. It seem flutter render have some problem in this case. I will try the scroll widget later, thank you.